# How to add background to android webview?

Tags: android, webview

I tried to add background to the webview in my android application. I tried both webview.setBackgroundResource() and webview.setBackgroundDrawable() .But not working

Any one help me how to do this

Answer (score 4):

In addition to setting the background drawable, you need to set the background color to transparent so the drawable shows through:

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```